# VB.Net: Winforms Designer: Use verbs from custom control in parent custom control

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms-designer

We're developing a custom control (to make our lives easier), which included a customs (external) grid control and some default buttons and text. The grid control has the option to add columns by clicking the small arrow on the top right of the grid in designer, like shown in the picture.

[image]

We want to keep this option when putting our new custom control on a (win)form. Is there any way we can achieve this?

I've already looked into the 'verbs' and I can add my own custom verbs to the new control, but I'm not sure the arrow is a verb (as it does not show the option on the bottom of the properties). I also haven't been able to find how to use the verbs from the grid control.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I believe that that little arrow is a smart tag and you can then access verbs and/or do other things within that. I've never created one myself but my first search yielded [this](https://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/35093) early on.

Comment: It's good to know the name of the beast. Any idea how I can call the smart tag of a component inside my component and link them through?

Comment: None at all. No experience in this area.

Comment: You could just expose the Grid Control using simple Designer derived from  `ParentControlDesigner`, to enable design mode of that specific control, so its Smart Tags handle would be accessible in design mode directly. Btw, with custom control do you actually mean Custom Control or UserControl?

Comment: Otherwise, you could add an Action List to your own *Control* (exposed through Smart Tags) and perform the same tasks (Add a Column / Rows, enable/disable some properties or whatever else).

Comment: UserControl. How do you mean: "enable design mode of that specific control"? I have a ParentControlDesigner for the UserControl. How can I enable designmode of the gridcontrol?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution to my problem.
I thought the way to add columns was a custom control when in reality, it was a default CollectionEditor. This, in combination with Smart Tag, solved my problem.